# Is Fortran easier to optimize than C for heavy calculations?

Tags: c, performance, fortran

From time to time I read that Fortran is or can be faster then C for heavy calculations. Is that really true? I must admit that I hardly know Fortran, but the Fortran code I have seen so far did not show that the language has features that C doesn't have.

If it is true, please tell me why. Please don't tell me what languages or libs are good for number crunching, I don't intend to write an app or lib to do that, I'm just curious.

Comment: Notreally subjective from the answers given below.
The correct title is "Are there any fundemental architectural reasons why a Fortran compiler MIGHT produce better optomised code than a C compiler" but that's just being nit-picking.

Comment: The question is too broad (Fortran is faster than C in which problem domain?), but I don't think the following discussion is subjective. We can produce a small code that proves/disproves any claim, as long as the problem is specific enough

Comment: Note that you don't need to write your program in Fortran if all you want to do is call some Fortran libraries. One can easily call Fortran code from C, all you need to remember about is name mangling, passing every variable by reference and different matrix ordering.

Comment: Right. Also, strings are a little weird.

Comment: Why do noobies always ask is this faster than that type questions ? Half the time they worry about nonsense functions that take a few cycles every other hour.

Comment: @sixlettervariables although you and I already know the answer, it is a question that occurs to most people early in their careers and its important to understand the answer. Rather than post a dismissive comment why not find an answer you agree with and give +1

Comment: @MarkJ: good point, I've voted to close as Not Constructive.

Comment: Can I add a romantic view (as fortran programmer). At that time we were coding for numbers and not for applications in the modern view. We knew, because we could, the memory mapping of any matrix, this is why we could use commons and mimic C pointers. And to answer the question: yes, at that time you had fortran optimized compilers. But less romantic: get a blas or lapack in any other programming language.

Comment: On a modern CPU with branch prediction, hierarchical memory and long pipelines, the answer is most definitely "no". C code tends to be faster than Fortran, even for numerical work. But there are other reasons to choose Fortran: C is a semi-portable high-level assembler. Fortran is a high-level language which is very portable, very readable, and easier to debug. It gives high performance with less effort, and is much easier to use than C. But faster? Not in 2015. The pointer aliasing problem in C is taken care of by modern CPU design and C compilers. It does not hurt as much as it did in 1980.

Comment: Fortran is a sledgehammer, it does a few things well.  C is swiss army knife.  If I want to access algorithms with quad precision, distributed/paralleized, blas, linpack or dsp functions as fast as possible without worrying about nul pointers and pointers to pointers to pointers, fortran wins.  Even Matlabs underlying numerical processing libraries are still use fortran code.

Comment: I'm not at all expert on this subject (ultra-low level - i.e. register level - optimisations), and found the answers very interesting.

Comment: ... continued! ...

But whilst I'm sure this must have once been a subject of passionate debate, it stikes me as of very little relevance todays as the hardware landscape of today is so very different.

Nowadays, the availability of GPU/APU-specific languages like OpenCL and CUDA makes the question of whether C or FORTRAN is faster moot. Neither is the fastest language for number-crunching, by a factor of anywhere between 10 and 100+, simply because they don't run on GPU/APU hardware.

Answer (score 515, accepted):

The languages have similar feature-sets. The performance difference comes from the fact that Fortran says aliasing is not allowed, unless an EQUIVALENCE statement is used. Any code that has aliasing is not valid Fortran, but it is up to the programmer and not the compiler to detect these errors. Thus Fortran compilers ignore possible aliasing of memory pointers and allow them to generate more efficient code. Take a look at this little example in C:

```
void transform (float *output, float const * input, float const * matrix, int *n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<*n; i++)
    {
        float x = input[i*2+0];
        float y = input[i*2+1];
        output[i*2+0] = matrix[0] * x + matrix[1] * y;
        output[i*2+1] = matrix[2] * x + matrix[3] * y;
    }
}
```

This function would run slower than the Fortran counterpart after optimization. Why so? If you write values into the output array, you may change the values of matrix. After all, the pointers could overlap and point to the same chunk of memory (including the `int` pointer!). The C compiler is forced to reload the four matrix values from memory for all computations.

In Fortran the compiler can load the matrix values once and store them in registers. It can do so because the Fortran compiler assumes pointers/arrays do not overlap in memory.

Fortunately, the [`restrict`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) keyword and strict-aliasing have been introduced to the C99 standard to address this problem. It's well supported in most C++ compilers these days as well. The keyword allows you to give the compiler a hint that the programmer promises that a pointer does not alias with any other pointer. The strict-aliasing means that the programmer promises that pointers of different type will never overlap, for example a `double*` will not overlap with an `int*` (with the specific exception that `char*` and `void*` can overlap with anything).

If you use them you will get the same speed from C and Fortran. However, the ability to use the `restrict` keyword only with performance critical functions means that C (and C++) programs are much safer and easier to write. For example, consider the invalid Fortran code: `CALL TRANSFORM(A(1, 30), A(2, 31), A(3, 32), 30)`, which most Fortran compilers will happily compile without any warning but introduces a bug that only shows up on some compilers, on some hardware and with some optimization options.

Comment: Aside from the restrict keyword, most compilers have had command line optimization flags to instruct the compiler to not worry about aliasing. Since doing actual aliasing is pretty rare, I consider that level of optimization the starting point default.

Comment: Additionally, without the flag or the new keyword, in C just assign pointer based operations through an automatic variable. This hints to the compiler that aliasing can be ignored and while it looks like more code, you'll actually end up with the fastest possible result through the optimizer

Comment: "rare" may or may not be a good reason to have flaky nondeterministic bugs.  I've seen it in cases where a function is used to process data either in-place or out-of-place.

Comment: All true and valid, jeff. However, I don't consider the "assume no aliasing"-switch safe. It can break code inherited from other projects in so subtle ways that I'd rather not use it. I've become a restrict-nazi for that reason :-)

Comment: Other team members that aren't yet that experienced are a risk as well if you force no aliasing. They may write perfectly fine code that does rely on aliasing to work.

Comment: Fortran is also able to automatically split calculations like this over multiple cores/CPUS because it knows that the parts of an arry cannot overlap.

Comment: @mgb: with the appropriate markup in place to enable these features.

Comment: To my second point, you don't have to use the no alias compiler switch. Just write the code so that the pointer based loads are assigned into an automatic variable first and then work with the automatics from there. It will look more verbose, but it will optimize down perfectly by the compiler.

Comment: Jeff, I agree on the auto variables and I think it's also good practice to write code that way. It not only hints the compiler, it makes clear that you don't assume aliasing as well. Nice to have if you have to touch the code a year after writing.

Comment: I love these kinds of discussions - most people (in general) don't appreciate the subtle issues on this kind of stuff. Good exchange of thoughts - Thanks!

Comment: A good example is the mere existence of memcpy() vs. memmove(). Unlike memcpy(), memmove() copes with overlapping areas, therefore memcpy() can be faster then memmove(). This issue was sufficient reason for somebody to include two function instead of one into the standard library.

Comment: Memcpy() vs. Memmove() is NOT a good example really. Different algorithms being used. memcpy() is a simpler (trivial) algorithm BECAUSE by definition it assumes the areas do not overlap. memmove() has to do more checks and a more complicated order of copy ops BECAUSE the areas MAY overlap.

Comment: I think that was Sebastian's point - because of the complexity/flexibility of C memory handling, even something as simple as moving memory is tricky.

Comment: My point is to copy an array in C one can use both memcpy() and memmove(). The choice depends on context. And in Fortran one have to make no such choice due to stronger aliasing rules.

Comment: I'd like to see some benchmark evidence that Fortran is faster than C. Don't suppose you have any refs?

Comment: You didn't mention the other thing in your C code that is slower: The exit condition in the C version has to be rechecked every iteration.

In your example that could be optimized out, but it couldn't if there was something in the loop potentially modifying n (or i).

Comment: ted, if the compiler can figure out how to put it outside the loop, it is allowed to do so, because of the as-if rule, whether or not the n is modified doesn't matter

Comment: Just to be contrary, let me point out that if routine A contains a loop, and routine B is called inside the loop, B probably takes most of the cycles. Optimizing the loop in A buys you very little.

Comment: As I recall, the EQUIVALENCE keyword, allowed you to some kinds of array overlaps.   Would that have an effect on the aliasing in a fortran program?

Comment: @MitchWheat: "I'd like to see some benchmark evidence that Fortran is faster than C. Don't suppose you have any refs?". Blitz++ strived to attain Fortran-level performance from C++ and had lots of benchmarks comparing them. The Successive Over-Relaxation task from the SciMark2 benchmark suite is affected by aliasing and, consequently, Java beat C and C++ there so you might like to try it in Fortran too.

Comment: Your `call transform` example doesn't have much sense.

Comment: @VladimirF why doesn't it have much sense?

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck probably because the actual arguments will be aliased and as such it is invalid Fortran with undefined behavior.  It doesn't make much sense to say "C is safer because Fortran allows me to write non-standard code with undefined behavior".  C will happily let you enter the land of non-standard code with undefined behavior as well.

Comment: *you may change the values of `matrix`* - is this so? Why? How to see that? And: Why is the `* n` passed as pointer?

Comment: There is even a better feature: A fortran programmer think fortran. I remember myself thinking about memory allocation while coding. I remember myself getting 10x factor in optimizing other codes. All of this just because it is an old straight forward programming language.

Comment: @embert, the `matrix` array could overlap with the `output` array. `transform(arr, arr, arr, &n)` is a valid function call supposing the array `arr` is large enough.

Comment: Fortran has a similar feature set as C? Really? First, which Fortran? The current popular Fortran standards (2003/2008) = super flexible module standard, OO (for those who care), native parallel programming support (do parallel), native distributed computing support (co-array fortran). If you start your program from scratch, it's so much easier to write a parallel numerical application. Also, interfacing with C libs is easy via the iso_c_binding module.

Comment: Is the ***only*** performance benefit of Fortran, the one associated with aliasing?

Comment: "[On the other hand C is stack dynamic. This allows for more flexible programming, but wasted memory and slower execution. Try declaring your C variables as static, and see if you can close the performance gap.](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-is-fortran-so-fast.169974/)" But the next answer starts with "Static vs dynamic storage allocation has nothing to do with the speed difference (and for modern compilers, there IS no speed difference worth botherig about)".

Comment: Your answer jumps the shark at the claim that C is safer than Fortran where `restrict` is not used.

Answer (score 181):

### Yes, in 1980; in 2008? depends

When I started programming professionally the speed dominance of Fortran was just being challenged. I remember [reading about it in Dr. Dobbs](http://web.archive.org/web/20090401205830/http://ubiety.uwaterloo.ca/~tveldhui/papers/DrDobbs2/drdobbs2.html) and telling the older programmers about the article--they laughed.

So I have two views about this, theoretical and practical. *In theory* Fortran today has no intrinsic advantage to C/C++ or even any language that allows assembly code. *In practice* Fortran today still enjoys the benefits of legacy of a history and culture built around optimization of numerical code.

Up until and including Fortran 77, language design considerations had optimization as a main focus. Due to the state of compiler theory and technology, this often meant *restricting* features and capability in order to give the compiler the best shot at optimizing the code. A good analogy is to think of Fortran 77 as a professional race car that sacrifices features for speed. These days compilers have gotten better across all languages and features for programmer productivity are more valued. However, there are still places where the people are mainly concerned with speed in scientific computing; these people most likely have inherited code, training and culture from people who themselves were Fortran programmers.

When one starts talking about optimization of code there are many issues and the best way to get a feel for this is [to lurk where people are whose job it is to have fast numerical code](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=169974). But keep in mind that such critically sensitive code is usually a small fraction of the overall lines of code and very specialized: A lot of Fortran code is just as "inefficient" as a lot of other code in other languages and [optimization should not even be a primary concern of such code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28computer_science%29#When_to_optimize).

A wonderful place to start in learning about the history and culture of Fortran is wikipedia. [The Fortran Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) is superb and I very much appreciate those who have taken the time and effort to make it of value for the Fortran community.

(A shortened version of this answer would have been a comment in the excellent thread started by **Nils** but I don't have the karma to do that. Actually, I probably wouldn't have written anything at all but for that this thread has actual information content and sharing as opposed to flame wars and language bigotry, which is my main experience with this subject. I was overwhelmed and had to share the love.)

Comment: the link: http://web.archive.org/web/20090401205830/http://ubiety.uwaterloo.ca/~tveldhui/papers/DrDobbs2/drdobbs2.html no longer works. Is there an alternative link?

Answer (score 70):

To some extent Fortran has been designed keeping compiler optimization in mind. The language supports whole array operations where compilers can exploit parallelism (specially on multi-core processors). For example,

Dense matrix multiplication is simply:

```
matmul(a,b)
```

L2 norm of a vector x is:

```
sqrt(sum(x**2))
```

Moreover statements such as `FORALL`, `PURE` & `ELEMENTAL` procedures etc. further help to optimize code. Even pointers in Fortran arent as flexible as C because of this simple reason.

The upcoming Fortran standard (2008) has co-arrays which allows you to easily write parallel code. G95 (open source) and compilers from CRAY already support it.

So yes Fortran can be fast simply because compilers can optimize/parallelize it better than C/C++. But again like everything else in life there are good compilers and bad compilers.

Comment: You may wish to read https://pimiddy.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/pure-functions-in-cc/ and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0078r0.pdf as well.

Comment: The ```forall``` construct is deprecated because compilers couldn’t optimize the code well. The replacement is ```do concurrent```.
Also, the code ```sqrt(sum(x**2))``` looks inefficient, because the compiler probably constructs the whole vector ```x**2```. I would guess that a loop is better, but it’s undoubtedly best to call the intrinsic ```norm2``` function.

Answer (score 42):

It is funny that a lot of answers here from not knowing the languages. This is especially true for C/C++ programmers who have opened and old FORTRAN 77 code and discuss the weaknesses.

I suppose that the speed issue is mostly a question between C/C++ and Fortran. In a Huge code, it always depends on the programmer. There are some features of the language that Fortran outperforms and some features which C does. So, in 2011, no one can really say which one is faster.

About the language itself, Fortran nowadays supports Full OOP features and it is fully backward compatible. I have used the Fortran 2003 thoroughly and I would say it was just delightful to use it. In some aspects, Fortran 2003 is still behind C++ but let's look at the usage. Fortran is mostly used for Numerical Computation, and nobody uses fancy C++ OOP features because of speed reasons. In high performance computing, C++ has almost no place to go(have a look at the MPI standard and you'll see that C++ has been deprecated!).

Nowadays, you can simply do mixed language programming with Fortran and C/C++. There are even interfaces for GTK+ in Fortran. There are free compilers (gfortran, g95) and many excellent commercial ones.

Comment: Could you please add a source, specific experience, or scientific institute /high performance computing agency that is either moving away from C++ for future projects or rewriting c++ projects to another language. I am only asking because I know at least two scientific institutions, Sandia and CERN, that heavily use c++ for their high performance modeling. Additionally Sandia converted one of their modeling software (LAMMPS) over from fortran to c++ adding in a number of awesome enhancements.

Comment: LAMMPS is written in extremely simple C++ that does not take advantage of most of the modern features of the language.  It represents the C++ that Fortran programmers who know C write after learning C++98.  This is not to say LAMMPS is poorly written, just that it is not the example you want to  cite when advocating for C++ in HPC.

Answer (score 33):

There are several reasons why Fortran could be faster. However the amount they matter is so inconsequential or can be worked around anyways, that it shouldn't matter. The main reason to use Fortran nowadays is maintaining or extending legacy applications.

- PURE and ELEMENTAL keywords on functions. These are functions that have no side effects. This allows optimizations in certain cases where the compiler knows the same function will be called with the same values. *Note: GCC implements "pure" as an extension to the language. Other compilers may as well. Inter-module analysis can also perform this optimization but it is difficult.*
- standard set of functions that deal with arrays, not individual elements. Stuff like sin(), log(), sqrt() take arrays instead of scalars. This makes it easier to optimize the routine. *Auto-vectorization gives the same benefits in most cases if these functions are inline or builtins*
- Builtin complex type. In theory this could allow the compiler to reorder or eliminate certain instructions in certain cases, but likely you'd see the same benefit with the `struct { double re; double im; };` idiom used in C. It makes for faster development though as operators work on complex types in Fortran.

Comment: "but likely you'd see the same benefit with the struct `{ double re, im; };` idiom used in C". C compilers will most likely return that struct in sret form with the caller stack allocating space, passing a pointer to the callee that fills it in. That is several times slower than returning multiple values in registers as a Fortran compiler would. Note that C99 fixed this in the special case of complex.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with your main reason. I personally like to use fortran for math heavy code where arrays and math functions are the most important part of the code. But I know for a fact in a lot of government institutions and banks they continue to use fortran to maintain or extend legacy code. I personally used fortran to extend code a professor on my Ph.D. committee wrote.

Comment: Your statement, "the main reason to use Fortran nowadays is maintaining or extending legacy applications", is completely wrong. I have yet to see any other programming language even remotely close to the features Fortran provides, especially for Mathematical applications. You already named a few of them, such as superb array support, built-in complex arithmetic, pure or elemental functions - and I could name more as well. That alone is enough to prove your statement above is wrong.

Answer (score 31):

I think the key point in favor of Fortran is that it is a language slightly more suited for expressing vector- and array-based math.  The pointer analysis issue pointed out above is real in practice, since portable code cannot really assume that you can tell a compiler something.  There is ALWAYS an advantage to expression computaitons in a manner closer to how the domain looks.  C does not really have arrays at all, if  you look closely, just something that kind of behaves like it. Fortran has real arrawys. Which makes it easier to compile for certain types of algorithms especially for parallel machines.

Deep down in things like run-time system and calling conventions, C and modern Fortran are sufficiently similar that it is hard to see what would make a difference.  Note that C here is really base C: C++ is a totally different issue with very different performance characteristics.

Answer (score 29):

There is no such thing as one language being faster than another, so the proper answer is **no**.

What you really have to ask is "is code compiled with Fortran compiler X faster than equivalent code compiled with C compiler Y?" The answer to that question of course depends on which two compilers you pick.

Another question one could ask would be along the lines of "Given the same amount of effort put into optimizing in their compilers, which compiler would produce faster code?"
The answer to this would in fact be *Fortran*. Fortran compilers have certian advantages:

- Fortran had to compete with Assembly back in the day when some vowed never to use compilers, so it was designed for speed. C was designed to be flexible.
- Fortran's niche has been number crunching. In this domain code is *never* fast enough. So there's always been a lot of pressure to keep the language efficient.
- Most of the research in compiler optimizations is done by people interested in speeding up Fortran number crunching code, so optimizing Fortran code is a much better known problem than optimizing any other compiled language, and new innovations show up in Fortran compilers first.
- **Biggie**: C encourages much more pointer use than Fortran. This drasticly increases the potential scope of any data item in a C program, which makes them far harder to optimize. Note that Ada is also way better than C in this realm, and is a much more modern OO Language than the commonly found Fortran77. If you want an OO langauge that can generate faster code than C, this is an option for you.
- Due again to its number-crunching niche, the customers of Fortran compilers tend to care more about optimization than the customers of C compilers.

However, there is nothing stopping someone from putting a ton of effort into their C compiler's optimization, and making it generate better code than their platform's Fortran compiler. In fact, the larger sales generated by C compilers makes this scenario quite feasible

Comment: I agree. And may I add that when Fortran was introduced (it was the first high level language) in the late 50's early 60's many were skeptical about how efficient it could be. Therefore its developers had to prove that Fortran could be efficient and useful and set about to "optimize it to death" just to prove their point. C came much later (early to mid 70's) and had nothing to prove, so to speak. But by this time a lot of Fortran code had been written so the scientific community stuck to it and still does. I don't program Fortran but I've learned to link to call Fortran subroutines from C++.

Comment: The research on compiler optimization has been more diverse than you seem to think. The history of LISP implementations, for example, is full of successes at doing number crunching faster than Fortran (which remains the default contender to challenge). Also, a huge part of compiler optimization has targeted intermediate representations of the compiler, which means that, differences in semantics aside (like aliasing), they apply to any programming language of a given class.

Comment: The idea is repeated a lot, but it's a bit disingenuous to say that there's no consequences for efficiency inherent to a programming language design. Some programming language features necessarily lead to inefficiencies because they limit the information available at compile time.

Comment: @Praxeolitic - That is quite correct (which is why I am pleased that I said no such thing).

Comment: @T.E.D. Honestly, coming back here a few months later I have no idea why I left that comment on your answer. Maybe I meant to leave it somewhere else? X-P

Comment: This might be one of the best answers!

Answer (score 21):

There is another item where Fortran is different than C - and potentially faster. Fortran has better optimization rules than C.  In Fortran, the evaluation order of an expressions is not defined, which allows the compiler to optimize it - if one wants to force a certain order, one has to use parentheses. In C the order is much stricter, but with "-fast" options, they are more relaxed and "(...)" are also ignored. I think Fortran has a way which lies nicely in the middle. (Well, IEEE makes the live more difficult as certain evaluation-order changes require that no overflows occur, which either has to be ignored or hampers the evaluation).

Another area of smarter rules are complex numbers. Not only that it took until C 99 that C had them, also the rules govern them is better in Fortran; since the Fortran library of gfortran is partially written in C but implements the Fortran semantics, GCC gained the option (which can also be used with "normal" C programs):

> -fcx-fortran-rules
>   Complex multiplication and division follow Fortran rules.  Range reduction is done as part of complex division, but there is no checking whether the result of a complex multiplication or division is "NaN + I*NaN", with an attempt to rescue the situation in that case.

The alias rules mentioned above is another bonus and also - at least in principle - the whole-array operations, which if taken properly into account by the optimizer of the compiler, can lead faster code. On the contra side are that certain operation take more time, e.g. if one does an assignment to an allocatable array, there are lots of checks necessary (reallocate? [Fortran 2003 feature], has the array strides, etc.), which make the simple operation more complex behind the scenes - and thus slower, but makes the language more powerful. On the other hand, the array operations with flexible bounds and strides makes it easier to write code - and the compiler is usually better optimizing code than a user.

In total, I think both C and Fortran are about equally fast; the choice should be more which language does one like more or whether using the whole-array operations of Fortran  and its better portability are more useful -- or the better interfacing to system and graphical-user-interface libraries in C.

Comment: What is there to meaningfully "rescue" in the Nan+INan case?  What makes infinities different from NaN is that infinities are signed.  Operations involving non-complex infinities that would yield a muddled sign yield NaN and I see no reason complex numbers should do otherwise.  If one multiples (DBL_MAX,DBL_MAX) by (2,2), squares the result, and then squares that result, what should be the sign of the result in the absence of overflow?  What is one instead multiples it by (1.001,DBL_MAX)?  I'd regard (NaN,NaN) as the correct answer, and any combination of infinity and NaN as nonsensical.

Answer (score 15):

Any speed differences between Fortran and C will be more a function of compiler optimizations and the underlying math library used by the particular compiler.  There is nothing intrinsic to Fortran that would make it faster than C.

Anyway, a good programmer can write Fortran in any language.

Comment: @Scott Clawson: you got -1'd and I don't know why. +1'd to remedy this. However, something to take into account is Fortran has been around longer than a lot of our parents have been. Lots of time spent optimizing compiler output :D

Comment: I agree. I had just posted a very similar answer in parallel.

Comment: Pointer alias issue in C has been raised by others, but there are several methods the programmer can use on modern compilers to deal with that, so I still agree.

Comment: @Kluge: "There is nothing intrinsic to Fortran that would make it faster than C". Pointer aliasing, returning compound values in registers, built-in higher-level numerical constructs...

Answer (score 15):

There is nothing about the *languages* Fortran and C which makes one faster than the other for specific purposes.  There are things about specific *compilers* for each of these languages which make some favorable for certain tasks more than others.

For many years, Fortran compilers existed which could do black magic to your numeric routines, making many important computations insanely fast.  The contemporary C compilers couldn't do it as well.  As a result, a number of great libraries of code grew in Fortran.  If you want to use these well tested, mature, wonderful libraries, you break out the Fortran compiler.

My informal observations show that these days people code their heavy computational stuff in any old language, and if it takes a while they find time on some cheap compute cluster.  Moore's Law makes fools of us all.

Comment: *Almost* upmodded this. The problem is that Fortran *does* have some inherent advantages. However, you are quite corrent that the important thing to look at is the compier, not the language.

Answer (score 15):

I compare speed of Fortran, C, and C++ with the classic Levine-Callahan-Dongarra benchmark from netlib.  The multiple language version, with OpenMP, is
http://sites.google.com/site/tprincesite/levine-callahan-dongarra-vectors
The C is uglier, as it began with automatic translation, plus insertion of restrict and pragmas for certain compilers.
C++ is just C with STL templates where applicable.  To my view, the STL is a mixed bag as to whether it improves maintainability.

There is only minimal exercise of automatic function in-lining to see to what extent it improves optimization, since the examples are based on traditional Fortran practice where little reliance is place on in-lining.

The C/C++ compiler which has by far the most widespread usage lacks auto-vectorization, on which these benchmarks rely heavily.

Re the post which came just before this:  there are a couple of examples where parentheses are used in Fortran to dictate the faster or more accurate order of evaluation.  Known C compilers don't have options to observe the parentheses without disabling more important optimizations.

Comment: The ugly translation is required to overcome the aliasing problem. You have to give the compiler mock variables to tell it that byref variables implemented as pointers can be register-optimised.

Comment: So which one is faster?

Answer (score 15):

I'm a hobbyist programmer and i'm "average" at both language.
I find it easier to write fast Fortran code than C (or C++) code. Both Fortran and C are "historic" languages (by today standard), are heavily used, and have well supported free and commercial compiler.

I don't know if it's an historic fact but Fortran feel like it's built to be paralleled/distributed/vectorized/whatever-many-cores-ized. And today it's pretty much the "standard metric" when we're talking about speed : "does it scale ?"

For pure cpu crunching i love Fortran. For anything IO related i find it easier to work with C. (it's difficult in both case anyway).

Now of course, for parallel math intensive code you probably want to use your GPU. Both C and Fortran have a lot of more or less well integrated CUDA/OpenCL interface (and now OpenACC).

My moderately objective answer is : If you know both language equally well/poorly then i think Fortran is faster because i find it easier to write parallel/distributed code in Fortran than C. (once you understood that you can write "freeform" fortran and not just strict F77 code)

Here is a 2nd answer for those willing to downvote me because they don't like the 1st answer : Both language have the features required to write high-performance code. So it's dependent of the algorithm you're implementing (cpu intensive ? io intensive ? memory intensive?), the hardware (single cpu ? multi-core ? distribute supercomputer ? GPGPU ? FPGA ?), your skill and ultimately the compiler itself. Both C and Fortran have awesome compiler. (i'm seriously amazed by how advanced Fortran compilers are but so are C compilers).

PS : i'm glad you specifically excluded libs because i have a great deal of bad stuff to say about Fortran GUI libs. :)

Answer (score 13):

Quick and simple:
**Both are equally fast, but Fortran is simpler.**
Whats really faster in the end depends on the algorithm, but there is considerable no speed difference anyway. This is what I learned in a Fortran workshop at high performance computing center Stuttgard, Germany in 2015. I work both with Fortran and C and share this opinion.

**Explanation:**

C was designed to write operating systems. Hence it has more freedom than needed to write high performance code. In general this is no problem, but if one does not programm carefully, one can easily slow the code down.

Fortran was designed for scientific programming. For this reason, it supports writing fast code syntax-wise, as this is the main purpose of Fortran. In contrast to the public opinion, Fortran is not an outdated programming language. Its latest standard is 2010 and new compilers are published on a regular basis, as most high performance code is writen in Fortran. [Fortran further supports modern features as compiler directives (in C pragmas).](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-with-intel-composer-xe-2013-compiler-pragmas-and-directives)

**Example:**
*We want to give a large struct as an input argument to a function (fortran: subroutine). Within the function the argument is not altered.*

C supports both, call by reference and call by value, which is a handy feature. In our case, the programmer might by accident use call by value. This slows down things considerably, as the struct needs to be copied in within memory first.

Fortran works with call by reference only, which forces the programmer to copy the struct by hand, if he really wants a call by value operation. In our case fortran will be automatically as fast as the C version with call by reference.

Comment: Can you write a native parallel application in C (meaning, without calling any libraries?). No. Can you write a native parallel application in Fortran? Yes, in a few different ways. Ergo, Fortran is "faster". ALthough, to be fair, in 2010 when you wrote your comment, support for parallel do and co-array features of Fortran were probably not as widespread as they are now.

Comment: @MaliRemorker He wrote this in 2016, not in 2010.

Comment: The overhead of creating parallel processes is in my opinion not the most relevant factor for a programming language being called 'fast'. More relevant are practical considerations, like a non-performant peace of code. So it does not help anything if you save time once (when creating the parallel process) and waste it on multiple cores later. The term 'fast' should also consider non-parallel codes. For this reason, I can not see an argument against my point. Maybe your comment was ment as an independent answer?

Answer (score 12):

I was doing some extensive mathematics with FORTRAN and C for a couple of years. From my own experience I can tell that FORTRAN is sometimes really better than C but not for its speed (one can make C perform as fast as FORTRAN by using appropriate coding style) but rather because of very well optimized libraries like LAPACK (which can, however, be called from C code as well, either linking against LAPACK directly or using the LAPACKE interface for C), and because of great parallelization. On my opinion, FORTRAN is really awkward to work with, and its advantages are not good enough to cancel that drawback, so now I am using C+GSL to do calculations.

Answer (score 10):

I haven't heard that Fortan is significantly faster than C, but it might be conceivable tht in certain cases it would be faster. And the key is not in the language features that are present, but in those that (usually) absent.

An example are C pointers. C pointers are used pretty much everywhere, but the problem with pointers is that the compiler usually can't tell if they're pointing to the different parts of the same array.

For example if you wrote a strcpy routine that looked like this:

```
strcpy(char *d, const char* s)
{
  while(*d++ = *s++);
}
```

The compiler has to work under the assumption that the d and s might be overlapping arrays. So it can't perform an optimization that would produce different results when the arrays overlap. As you'd expect, this considerably restricts the kind of optimizations that can be performed.

[I should note that C99 has a "restrict" keyword that explictly tells the compilers that the pointers don't overlap. Also note that the Fortran too has pointers, with semantics different from those of C, but the pointers aren't ubiquitous as in C.]

But coming back to the C vs. Fortran issue, it is conceivable that a Fortran compiler is able to perform some optimizations that might not be possible for a (straightforwardly written) C program. So I wouldn't be too surprised by the claim. However, I do expect that the performance difference wouldn't be all that much. [~5-10%]

Answer (score 9):

Generally FORTRAN is slower than C.  C can use hardware level pointers allowing the programmer to hand-optimize.  FORTRAN (in most cases) doesn't have access to hardware memory addressing hacks.  (VAX FORTRAN is another story.)   I've used FORTRAN on and off since the '70's.  (Really.)

However, starting in the 90's FORTRAN has evolved to include specific language constructs that can be optimized into inherently parallel algorithms that *can* really scream on a multi-core processor.   For example, automatic Vectorizing allows multiple processors to handle each element in a vector of data concurrently.  16 processors -- 16 element vector -- processing takes 1/16th the time.

In C, you have to manage your own threads and design your algorithm carefully for multi-processing, and then use a bunch of API calls to make sure that the parallelism happens properly.

In FORTRAN, you only have to design your algorithm carefully for multi-processing.  The compiler and run-time can handle the rest for you.

You can read a little about [High Performance Fortran](http://www.hku.hk/cc/sp2/software/hpf/rice-hpf/hpf-tutorial.html), but you find a lot of dead links.  You're better off reading about Parallel Programming (like [OpenMP.org](http://openmp.org/wp/)) and how FORTRAN supports that.

Comment: @S.Lott: I couldn't imagine how awful C code would have to look to do as good as simply written Fortran for most of the codes we have here...and I'm a C programmer. You'll get better performance out of simpler code in Fortran. Not that you or I couldn't find a counterexample. :D

Comment: No compiler is going to spread a computation on 16 elements of a vector to 16 different CPUs. That'd be hundreds of times slower...

Comment: @sixlettervariales: Yup.  Fortran does it's thing well.  C does something else well.

Comment: @Greg Rogers: You'll have to take your issue up with Fortran Vectorization people, not me.  I'm just reporting what I read.  http://www.polyhedron.com/absoftlinux

Comment: -1 // "Generally FORTRAN is slower than C. This is true for almost everything." why? // an argument based on the ease of using multi-threading in Fortran vs C isn't saying something about the performance.

Comment: @steabert: multi-threading only exists for performance.  I'm not sure why you object to that.  Run-time performance depends on many, many things.  The language itself isn't relevant.  However.  C's use of pointers almost at the hardware level allows C to be faster than Fortran.

Comment: @S.Lott: "multi-threading only exists for performance". Err, no.

Comment: @S.Lott: "C's use of pointers almost at the hardware level allows C to be faster than Fortran". Err, no

Comment: "multi-threading only exists for performance"  It cannot have another purpose on this earth.  Rather than post silly opinions, please explain what point multithreading has that's not strictly (and only) performance related.

Comment: The link that you provided is already dead.  Care to provide another?

Comment: being able to deal with very large datasets is anotherpurpose of multithreading

Answer (score 5):

The faster code is not really up to the language, is the compiler so you can see the ms-vb "compiler" that generates bloated, slower and redundant object code that is tied together inside an ".exe", but powerBasic generates too way better code.
Object code made by a C and C++ compilers is generated in some phases (at least 2) but by design most Fortran compilers have at least 5 phases including high-level optimizations so by design Fortran will always have the capability to generate highly optimized code.
So at the end is the compiler not the language you should ask for, the best compiler i know is the Intel Fortran Compiler because you can get it on LINUX and Windows and you can use VS as the IDE, if you're looking for a cheap tigh compiler you can always relay on OpenWatcom.

More info about this:
http://ed-thelen.org/1401Project/1401-IBM-Systems-Journal-FORTRAN.html

Comment: "So at the end is the compiler not the language you should ask for, the best compiler i know is the Intel Fortran Compiler" I guess you could ask though "which language has better compilers" or "which language is better suited to writing high-performance compilers".

Answer (score 3):

Fortran has better I/O routines, e.g. the implied do facility gives flexibility that C's standard library can't match.

The Fortran compiler directly handles the more complex 
syntax involved, and as such syntax can't be easily reduced 
to argument passing form, C can't implement it efficiently.

Comment: Do you have benchmarks that show Fortran beating C for I/O?

Answer (score 3):

Fortran can handle array, especially multidimensional arrays, very conveniently. Slicing elements of multidimensional array in Fortran can be much easier than that in C/C++. C++ now has libraries can do the job, such as Boost or Eigen, but they are after all external libraries. In Fortran these functions are intrinsic.

Whether Fortran is faster or more convenient for developing mostly depends on the job you need to finish. As a scientific computation person for geophysics, I did most of computation in Fortran (I mean modern Fortran, >=F90).

Comment: And also whether Fortran is faster also depends on: the compiler you use (it matters!), for computation jobs whether you apply appropriate parallelization to the code, and how your code is written.

Comment: Kai I think it would be better if you put that comment into your answer. I can't do it because "too many edits are pending on Stack Overflow".

Answer (score 2):

Using modern standards and compiler, no!

Some of the folks here have suggested that FORTRAN is faster because the compiler doesn't need to worry about aliasing (and hence can make more assumptions during optimisation). However, this has been dealt with in C since the C99 (I think) standard with the inclusion of the restrict keyword. Which basically tells the compiler, that within a give scope, the pointer is not aliased. Furthermore C enables proper pointer arithmetic, where things like aliasing can be very useful in terms of performance and resource allocation. Although I think more recent version of FORTRAN enable the use of "proper" pointers.

For modern implementations C general outperforms FORTRAN (although it is very fast too).

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/fortran.html

EDIT:

A fair criticism of this seems to be that the benchmarking may be biased. Here is another source (relative to C) that puts result in more context:

http://julialang.org/benchmarks/

You can see that C typically outperforms Fortran in most instances (again see criticisms below that apply here too); as others have stated, benchmarking is an inexact science that can be easily loaded to favour one language over others. But it does put in context how Fortran and C have similar performance.

Comment: One would be a fool to believe anything about Fortran from a post that assumes it is still FORTRAN. That changed more than 25 years ago. Those tests cannot compare languages, because they use compilers from different vendors although both Intel and GCC have compilers for both C and Fortran. Therefore those comparisons are worthless.

Answer (score 0):

This is more than somewhat subjective, because it gets into the quality of compilers and such more than anything else. However, to more directly answer your question, speaking from a language/compiler standpoint there is nothing about Fortran over C that is going to make it inherently faster or better than C. If you are doing heavy math operations, it will come down to the quality of the compiler, the skill of the programmer in each language and the intrinsic math support libraries that support those operations to ultimately determine which is going to be faster for a given implementation.

EDIT: Other people such as @Nils have raised the good point about the difference in the use of pointers in C and the possibility for aliasing that perhaps makes the most naive implementations slower in C. However, there are ways to deal with that in C99, via compiler optimization flags and/or in how the C is actually written. This is well covered in @Nils answer and the subsequent comments that follow on his answer.

Comment: It sounds like a benchmark test of an algorithm.  Which takes less time, FORTRAN or C?  Doesn't sound subjective to me.  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Disagree. You are comparing the compilers, not the languages. I think the original question is if there is anything about the LANGUAGE that makes it inherently better. Other answers here are getting into some of the subtle questionable differences, but I think we most agree they are in the noise.

Comment: This isn't O(n) analysis of algorithms.  It's Performance.  Don't see how performance can be a hypothetic implementation-independent concept.  Guess I'm missing something.

Comment: -1: "there is nothing about Fortran over C that is going to make it inherently faster or better than C". Err, no.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the posts already present compelling arguments, so I will just add the proverbial 2 cents to a different aspect.

Being fortran faster or slower in terms of processing power in the end can have its importance, but if it takes 5 times more time to develop something in Fortran because:

- it lacks any good library for tasks different from pure number crunching
- it lack any decent tool for documentation and unit testing
- it's a language with very low expressivity, skyrocketing the number of lines of code.
- it has a very poor handling of strings
- it has an inane amount of issues among different compilers and architectures driving you crazy.
- it has a very poor IO strategy (READ/WRITE of sequential files. Yes, random access files exist but did you ever see them used?)
- it does not encourage good development practices, modularization.
- effective lack of a fully standard, fully compliant opensource compiler (both gfortran and g95 do not support everything)
- very poor interoperability with C (mangling: one underscore, two underscores, no underscore, in general one underscore but two if there's another underscore. and just let not delve into COMMON blocks...)

Then the issue is irrelevant. If something is slow, most of the time you cannot improve it beyond a given limit. If you want something faster, change the algorithm. In the end, computer time is cheap. Human time is not. Value the choice that reduces human time. If it increases computer time, it's cost effective anyway.

Comment: downvoted because although you raise interesting points which add to a discussion of fortrans benefits/drawbacks versus other languages (which I don't completely agree with), this isn't really an answer to the question...

Comment: @steabert: in fact, I said `I will just add the proverbial 2 cents to a different aspect`

Comment: +1 from me for some not-nitpicky answer. As you said, Fortran might be faster in some rare tasks (have not seen any personally). But the amount of time you waste for maintaining an unmaintainable language ruins any possible advantage.

Comment: -1. You seem to be thinking of Fortran in terms of F77. That was superseded by F90, F95, F03, **and** F08.

Comment: @KyleKanos: most of the points are still valid with F9X/F2k3, besides, the specs for 2k3 and 2k8 are probably impossible to implement fully, and in any case I don't want to wait until 2035. I code in C++ and python now.

Comment: Downvoted because it talks exclusively about one side of a trade-off. Development speed may matter for most general programming, but that doesn't make it the only valid trade-off. Fortran programmers are often scientists/engineers who value the simplicity of the language (FORmula TRANslation is extremely easy to learn and master. C/C++ is *not*), the excellent libraries (often used from other languages), and the speed (e.g. weather simulations that take days in Fortran, but months if written entirely in other languages).

Comment: -1 "use iso_c_binding"   there's nothing wrong with mixed language programming, as your python/C++ mix rightly demonstrates.

Comment: @Kyle: you would be surprised how much F77 is still relevant in my field.

Comment: Fortran supports many types of I/O.  I don't get your point about people not using features, that is their problem not Fortran's.  It does encourage modularization with "modules" of all things.  Very good interoperability with C using iso_c_binding, which is native Fortran.  Gfortran free compiler is pretty darn good.  It will never have every feature because new ones keep getting added.

Answer (score -3):

Fortran traditionally doesn't set options such as -fp:strict (which ifort requires to enable some of the features in USE IEEE_arithmetic, a part of f2003 standard).  Intel C++ also doesn't set -fp:strict as a default, but that is required for ERRNO handling, for example, and other C++ compilers don't make it convenient to turn off ERRNO or gain optimizations such as simd reduction. gcc and g++ have required me to set up Makefile to avoid using the dangerous combination -O3 -ffast-math -fopenmp -march=native.
Other than these issues, this question about relative performance gets more nit-picky and dependent on local rules about choice of compilers and options.

Comment: Recent gcc updates corrected the problem with combination of Openmp and fast-math.

Comment: This answer is really about users not understanding the default flags for their compilers, not the languages themselves.