# Fortran vs C++, does Fortran still hold any advantage in numerical analysis these days?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, fortran

With the rapid development of C++ compilers,especially the intel ones, and the abilities of directly applying SIMD functions in your C/C++ code, does Fortran still hold any real advantage in the world of numerical computations?

I am from an applied maths background, my job involves a lot of numerical analysis, computations, optimisations and such, with a strictly defined performance-requirement.

I hardly know anything about Fortran, I have some experience in C/CUDA/matlab(if you consider the latter as a computer language to begin with), and my daily task involves analysis of very large data (e.g. 10GB-large matrix), and it seems the program at least spend 2/3 of its time on memory-accessing (thats why I send some of its job to GPU), do you people think it may worth the effects for me to trying the fortran routine on at least some performance-critical part of my code to improve the performance of my program?

Because the complexity and things need to be done involved there, I will only go that routine if only there is significant performance benefit there, thanks in advance.

Comment: Fortran benefits from not having aliasing, so it can optimize a lot more aggressively. In C99 you can achieve something similar with `restrict`, though that's not part of C++. On the other hand, C++ allows you to use expression templates and inlining. So the answer is that "it depends on what you are doing", I suppose.

Comment: Few similar questions: [Is Fortran faster than C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146159/is-fortran-faster-than-c), [What advantages does modern Fortran have over modern C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821913/what-advantages-does-modern-fortran-have-over-modern-c), [How much better are Fortran compilers really?](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/how-much-better-are-fortran-compilers-really), not sure if it would be an exact duplicate though.

Comment: What do you mean by "program at least spend 2/3 of its time on memory-accessing?" Does that mean 2/3 of the time is spent loading a 10GB matrix?  Or do you mean your cache miss rate is too high?  Or your program is memory bandwidth limited?

Comment: Because the program has to pays alot of visits to some 10GB big matrices for every iteration, so yes, it can be memory bandwidth limited or high cache-miss or both (some of the work involves random-memory accessing, and yes, I know how to speed it up by reordered the data but there will be a huge performance hit elsewhere then, to simply prevent me from even trying that), as for sheer computations, simd intrinsics takes most part of the job, whilst gpu also helps a little, so I just dont know if fortran can do something better.

Comment: Try sending more of it to the GPU.

Answer (score 66):

Fortran has strict aliasing semantics compared to C++ and has been aggressively tuned for numerical performance for decades.  Algorithms that uses the CPU to work with arrays of data often have the potential to benefit from a Fortran implementation.

The programming languages shootout should not be taken too seriously, but of the 15 benchmarks, Fortran ranks #1 for speed on *four* of them (for Intel Q6600 one core), more than any other single language.  You can see that the benchmarks where Fortran shines are the heavily numerical ones:

- [spectral norm](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/performance.php?test=spectralnorm) 27% faster
- [fasta](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/performance.php?test=fasta) 67% faster
- [mandelbrot](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/performance.php?test=mandelbrot) 56% faster
- [pidigits](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/performance.php?test=pidigits) 18% faster

Counterexample:

- [k-nucleotide](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/performance.php?test=knucleotide) 500% slower (this benchmark focuses heavily on more sophisticated data structures and string processing, which is not Fortran's strength)

You can also see a summary page "[how many times slower](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programs-are-fastest.html)" that shows that out of all implementations, the Fortran code is on average closest to the fastest implementation for each benchmark -- although the quantile bars are much larger than for C++, indicating Fortran is unsuited for some tasks that C++ is good at, but you should know that already.

So the questions you will need to ask yourself are:

1. Is the speed of this function so critical that reimplementing it in Fortran is worth my time?
2. Is performance so important that my investment in learning Fortran will pay off?
3. Is it possible to use a library like ATLAS instead of writing the code myself?

Answering these questions would require detailed knowledge of your code base and business model, so I can't answer those.  But yes, Fortran implementations are often faster than C++ implementations.

Another factor in your decision is the amount of sample code and the quantity of reference implementations available.  Fortran's strong history means that there is a wealth of numerical code available for download and even with a trip to the library.  As always you will need to sift through it to find the good stuff.

Comment: Comparing these two languages based on the shootout is really flawed. At least one should use the same vendor.

Comment: @VladimirF: Yes, it is flawed.  I don't think there is a way to compare languages that isn't flawed.

Comment: As I say, don't compare apples and oranges, but g++ with gfortran and ifort with intel's c++.

Comment: BTW, that will probably reduce the speed advantage of Fortran over C++ and still it won't stop me from preferring Fortran, because the true advantages are somewhere else. The language simplicity and the nice syntax of array operations.

Comment: @VladimirF FYI, intel c compiler has started to support array notations as part of the cilk extension. So the simple, pretty oneliner code is now possible.

Comment: @KingCrimson Yes, but thas is essentially a new language.

Comment: Many people say that c++ is slower than fortran specially for numerical programming. But using gfortran and g++, I always managed to optimize my c++ code to be at least as fast as my fortran code. I found that the main reason that sometimes c++ is slower is compiler assumption about pointer aliasing that can be cured simply by restrict keyword.

Comment: @M.Elmi: Yes, that is exactly it.  But C++ has no restrict keyword, it is not part of the standard.

Comment: Nice answer, but would have loved to see C++ vs Fortran comparisons complemented with C vs Fortran comparisons also.

Answer (score 18):

The complete and correct answer to your question is, "yes, Fortran does hold some advantages".

C++ also holds some, different, advantages.  So do Python, R, etc etc.   They're different languages.  It's easier and faster to do some things in one language, and some in others.  All are widely used in their communities, and for very good reasons.

Anything else, in the absence of more specific questions, is just noise and language-war-bait, which is why I've voted to close the question and hope others will too.

Answer (score 9):

Fortran is just naturally suited for numerical programming. You tend to have a large amount of numbers in such programs, typically arranged arrays. Arrays are first class citizens in Fortran and it is often pretty straight forward to translate numerical kernels from Matlab into Fortran.
Regarding potential performance advantages see the other answers, that cover this quite nicely. The baseline is probably you can create highly efficient numerical applications with most compiled languages today, but you might jump through some loops to get there. Fortran was carefully designed to allow the compiler to recognize most spots for optimizations, due to the language features. Of course you can also write arbitrary slow code with any compiled language, including Fortran.
In any case you should pick the tools as suited. Fortran suits numerical applications, C suits system related development. On a final remark, learning Fortran basics is not hard, and it is always worthwhile to have a look into other languages. This opens a different view on problems you want to solve.

Answer (score 9):

Also worth mentioning is that Fortran is a lot easier to master than C++. In fact, Fortran has a shorter language spec than plain C and it's syntax is arguably simpler. You can pick it up very quickly.

Meaning that if you are only interested in learning C++ or Fortran to solve a single specific problem you have at the moment (say, to speed up the bottlenecks in something you wrote in a prototyping language), Fortran might give you a better return on investment.

Comment: ( Also imho if your aim is building a skillset in the long term, then Rust would be my preferred option as of 2022. If you are specifically writing something that you will be calling from Python or Javascript it is just way easier to get something done )

Answer (score 2):

Fortran code is better for matrix and vector type operation in general. But you also can produce similar performance with c/c++ code by passing hints/suggestions to the compiler to produce similar quality vector instructions. One option that gave me good boost was not to assume memory aliasing among input variables that are array objects. This way, the compiler can aggressively do inner loop unrolling and pipelining for ILP where it can overlap loads and store operation across loop iteration with right prefetches.