# Optimizing Mandelbrot Set Calculation in C++ on a High-Performance CPU

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-optimization, simd

I've been experimenting with calculating the Mandelbrot set in C++ on my i9 CPU, which has 10 cores and 20 threads. Despite expecting fast computations given my CPU's capabilities, the actual performance has been surprisingly slow, and I'm trying to understand why.

Here's the core function used to calculate the number of iterations for each point in the set:

```
double calculateMandelbrotIterations(std::complex<double> c, int iterations) {
    std::complex<double> z = 0;
    double n = 0;
    while (abs(z*z) <= 2 && n <= iterations) {
        z = z * z + c;
        n++;
    } 
    return n;
}
```

According to technical specifications, my CPU is capable of 800 GFLOPS, or 80 GFLOPS per core. For rendering a 1000x1000 pixel image with a maximum iteration depth of 1000, it appears I would invoke the above function approximately 10 billion times. Given an estimated 20-30 CPU cycles per function call, the expected computation time should be around:

```
width * height * iterations * operations / gflops 
1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 20 / 80e9 = 0.25 seconds
```

However, the actual computation takes around 6.5 seconds on average, which is 26 times slower than expected.

Inspecting the assembly code generated (as seen on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/d6WsGbbqq)), it appears that SIMD optimizations are not being utilized despite the use of SIMD operations, which significantly reduces the theoretical throughput of my CPU from being able to run 8 float operations per cycle per core down to just 1. This adjustment suggests an overall performance of 10 GFLOPS, yet this is still a factor of 3 short from my calculations.

I suspect that cache performance isn't the bottleneck since the data for a 1000x1000 image should fit within the L3 cache, and all computations are successively performed on contiguous memory locations.

It's worth noting that I'm focusing on optimizing single-threaded performance and not looking to use multiple threads or GPU acceleration at this stage. My goal is to understand and improve the performance of the current setup.

1. Why is there such a significant discrepancy between the theoretical and actual performance of my Mandelbrot set calculations?
2. How can I optimize my C++ code to better utilize the CPU's capabilities, specifically regarding SIMD instructions and maximizing FLOPS utilization?
3. Are there any compiler flags or code modifications that I could use to enhance SIMD utilization for this calculation?

#### Core Code

```
#pragma once

#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

#define SMOOTH

struct Context {
    unsigned int width = 1000;
    unsigned int height = 1000;
    unsigned int iterations = 256;
    double zoom = 1.0;
    std::complex<double> center = {0, 0};
};

template<typename Func>
void forEachPixel(int start, int end, int width, Func func) {
    for (int y = start; y < end; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            func(x, y);
}

double calculateMandelbrotIterations(std::complex<double> c, const Context &ctx) {
    std::complex<double> z = 0;
    double n = 0;
    while (abs(z*z) <= 2 && n <= ctx.iterations) {
        z = z * z + c;
        n++;
    }

#ifdef SMOOTH
    if (n < ctx.iterations) {
        double log_zn = log(pow(z, 2)) / 2;
        double nu = log2(log_zn / log(2));
        n = n + 1 - nu;
    }
#endif

    return n;
}

void fillMandelbrotRegion(int start, int end, double *output, const Context &ctx) {
    const double aspectRatio = static_cast<double>(ctx.width) / ctx.height;
    const double scaleHeight = 4.0 / (ctx.zoom * aspectRatio);
    const double scaleWidth = 4.0 / ctx.zoom;

    forEachPixel(start, end, ctx.width, [&](int x, int y) {
        std::complex<double> c(
            ctx.center.real() + (x - ctx.width / 2.0) * scaleWidth / ctx.width,
            ctx.center.imag() + (y - ctx.height / 2.0) * scaleHeight / ctx.height
        );
        output[y * ctx.width + x] = calculateMandelbrotIterations(c, ctx);
    });
}
```

Comment: What compiler and compiler flags are you using?

Comment: SIMD is difficult for the compiler here as each `calculateMandelbrotIterations` function only operates on a single value. You can't do multiple `calculateMandelbrotIterations` at a time as each one will loop a different number of times. SIMD requires doing the exact same operations on multiple array elements

Comment: There are a few optimised implementations around https://www.google.com/search?q=simd+mandlebrot

Comment: I think Intel didn't start using "i9" until some time after Haswell, so max scalar FLOPs per core is 2/clock FMA which counts as 4 FLOPs.  (In this particular use-case, complex mul an add, probably not all the math ops can be FMA, but you can still get at least 2 FLOPs per cycle if you don't bottleneck on latency.  But that's tricky to avoid since FP ALU latency is 4 cycles for mul/fma, and for add on CPUs before Alder Lake.)  In your Godbolt link, you forgot to use `-march=x86-64-v3` or `-march=rocketlake` or anything like that which would let it use FMA.

Comment: *despite the use of SIMD operations* - the only "SIMD" operations in your godbolt link are `movapd` register copies.  Everything else is scalar, like `mulsd` (multiply Scalar Double-precision), `addsd`, and `ucomisd` (compare, with unordered not raising an FP-invalid exception.)

Comment: *the theoretical throughput of my CPU from being able to run 8 float operations per cycle per core* - huh?  Where did you get that low number?  That's just one vector of 8 floats doing one mul or add (not FMA) per clock, so 1/4 of the actual peak FLOP/cycle.  [Theoretical maximum performance (FLOPS ) of Intel Xeon E5-2640 v4 CPU, using only addition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68806471) / [FLOPS per cycle for sandy-bridge and haswell SSE2/AVX/AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15655835)

Comment: You could try putting two or more iterations inside the loop, reducing the overhead of evaluating the loop terminating criteria on every iteration.

Comment: Intel's OpenCL driver is successful in parallelizing by simple kernel code. But its C instead of C++, except for newest version. And this is for my AMD ryzen CPU. Surely it would be better on Intel since intel likes to optimize compiler for intel more. Also you need to count all taken steps per pixel. Its different per pixel so debugging needed to know per different image produced.

Answer (score 3):

The classic Mandelbrot calculation is not easy for a compiler to vectorize (it's not that hard for humans though). In order to do that, a compiler would have to inline `calculateMandelbrotIterations` into its caller, notice that it's both OK and desirable to *lengthen* the Mandelbrot iteration loop (as long as the `n` where it "should have ended" is remembered, also the "last" `z` if `smooth` is enabled), then vectorize it by running multiple copies of that loop simultaneously instead of applying vectorization to the loop itself. Or there may be alternative routes for a compiler to get there, but in any case it's hard.

Since the calculation involves a high latency loop-carried dependency, you would need extra independent calculations on top of vectorization in order to utilize the processor well.

Additionally, the code does a couple of unnecessary/inefficient things:

- `cabs` is called rather than inlined. `-ffast-math` made that call go away.
- The code is being unnecessarily careful with NaN, that also goes away with `-ffast-math`. (this is a common problem with `std::complex`)

`-ffast-math` is a risky option in general but for a Mandelbrot renderer it's probably fine.

Comment: Re: how to vectorize mandelbrot: [Fortran vs C: Mandelbrot benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54273809) links a manually-vectorized AVX and AVX-512 version.  https://web.archive.org/web/20160420233238/https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-intel-advanced-vector-extensions/ is an example from an Intel article introducing AVX, so they explain why they're doing what they're doing.  (I had to use the wayback machine because Intel seems to delete their excellent old articles.)  And see [some mandelbrot drawing routine from c to sse2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15986390)

Comment: The improvement is huge. 3x with the use of `-fast-math`